# Rails validation of mistyped numbers with allow_blank

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

When I, for example, enter 11q instead of 11 I get no error and the form is being saved as if nothing happened. Unfortunately Rails thinks that 11q is actually a nil.

this is my current validation line:

```
validates :order_retain_days, numericality: {in: 1..999, only_integer: true,  message: 'retain value must be an integer  between 1 and 999'}, allow_blank: true
```

fragment of db/schema.rb

```
create_table "order_details", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "order_retain_days"
end
```

How can I validate it if Javascript is turned off? I need to allow blank field or have the value within numeric range.

Comment: Changing the view so that we have text_field instead of numeric_field solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom validation:

```
validate :presence_and_numericality_of_order_retain_days
def presence_and_numericality_of_order_retain_day
  if self.order_retain_days && !self.order_retain_days=~ /insert your regex here/
    errors.add(order_retain_dats, 'retain value must be an integer  between 1 and 999')
  end
end
```

Comment: A browser, at least Safari, changes mistyped number to empty string. Custom validation will not work if you want to allow_blank. Getting rid of numeric_field in my view was the solution.

Comment: It does the custom validation is checking if the object is present and not matching the criteria then it will add to the error object, if not present it will pass. Check the method written above please.

Comment: You don't understand the point. The regex doesn't make sense if you have nothing to check it against. When you mistype a number, for example instead of 11 you type 11q in params you will see empty string. It is impossible to distinguish between empty string in params being result of leaving the field empty or being result of mistyped number.